Why is $E$ an elliptic curve, and how to calculate its $j$-invariant?
I am reading an example of Springer fiber written by Bernstein and Kazhdan.

Let $V$ and $V'$ be two $\mathbb C$-vector spaces, both of dimension $3$. Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3 \in \mathbb C$ be nonzero and distinct. Put
\begin{eqnarray}
Q & = & \{ [x_1,x_2,x_3] \in \mathbf P(V) | \sum_{i=1}^3 x_i^2 =0 \}, \nonumber \\
Q' & = & \{ [y_1,y_2,y_3] \in \mathbf P(V') | \sum_{i=1}^3 \lambda_i x_i^2=0 \}.\nonumber\end{eqnarray}
Define a bilinear form $\langle, \rangle$ on $V \times V'$ by setting $\langle (x_i), (y_i) \rangle$ to be $\sum_{i=1}^3 x_iy_i$. Put
$$E = \{ (l,l') \in Q \times Q' | \langle l,l' \rangle =0\}.$$
Then $E$ is an elliptic curve with Jacobi invariant
$$j(E) = 32(\sum_{i<j} \left( \mu_i-\mu_j)^2 \right)^3/\left(\prod_{i<j}(\mu_i-\mu_j)\right)^2,$$
where $\mu_i = \lambda_i^{-1}$ for $i=1,2,3$.

My question is, why is this statement true? The article reveals the fact that there is a $2$-fold covering of $E$ over $\mathbb P^1$ ramified at $4$ points. Why does this fact implies that $E$ is an elliptic curve? As far as I know, an elliptic curve is something given by an equation of the form $y^2+ay+b = x^3+cx^2+fx+g$. How can I write the equation corresponding to $E$?
Thank you!

The existence of such a double cover $\pi: E \to \mathbb{P}^1$ implies that $E$ has genus $1$ by the Riemann--Hurwitz formula. Let $g$ be the genus of $E$. Since $\mathbb{P}^1$ has genus $0$, then applying Riemann--Hurwitz yields
\begin{align*}
2g -2 = 2(2 \cdot 0 - 2) + 4 \cdot(2-1) = -4 + 4 = 0 \, ,
\end{align*}
so $g = 1$.
Let $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4 \in \mathbb{P}^1$ be the ramification values of $\pi$. If one of the ramification values, say $e_1$, is $\infty$, then $E$ is isomorphic to the elliptic curve $y^2 = (x - e_2)(x - e_3)(x - e_4)$. If none of the ramification values is $\infty$, we can reduce to this case by mapping $e_1$ to $\infty$ by the Möbius transformation $M: x \mapsto \frac{1}{x - e_1}$. Letting $e_i' = M(e_i)$ for $i = 2, 3, 4$, then $E$ is isomorphic to the elliptic curve $y^2 = (x - e_2')(x - e_3')(x - e_4')$.

Thank you very much for the answer. Please allow me to bring further questions according to your answer. 1. How can I do addition on $\mathbb P^1$? I can find definitions on the additive group structure on elliptic curves, but I don't know how to add two elements in $\mathbb P^1$.  2. How come $y^2 = (x-e_2)(x-e_3)(x-e_4) \in \mathbb C[x,y]$ for $e_1 = \infty, e_2,e_3,e_4 \in \mathbb P^1$?

There's isn't an addition law on all of $\mathbb{P}^1$, but $\mathbb{P}^1 \setminus {\infty}$ is just $\mathbb{C}$, so you can add non-infinite points. For your second question, the idea that we can choose a Weierstrass equation for the curve such that the double cover is the projection map $E \to \mathbb{P}^1$, $(x,y) \mapsto x$. Every elliptic curve can be written in Weierstrass form; see Silverman's The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, chapter III.3 for more details.
